# Android alpha and AlphaAnimation

Tags: android, animation, opacity, alpha

In imageAdapter class, I set the image alpha to 0.5 `handler.imageView.setAlpha(0.5f);` inside a try/catch.
It's made like this, and not inside the layout xml, because previous versions of android haves `int` instead of `float`, so, in the catch, setAlpha is 128.

In the activity, I have an `AlphaAnimation(float from, float to)` so I can make smoother transitions when sliding between items. I've put `from = 0.5f` to match the initial value, and `to = 1.0f` to full opaque image. I really achieved a part from this. The item that is not selected shows an alpha with 0.5, but when it's selected, it's not 100% opaque, just a bit more.

Activity code:

```
private View antView = null; //Last view seen
...
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        if(antView != null)
            setItemViewMode(antView, false);
        antView = v;
        setItemViewMode(v, true);
    }
});

//This method is to detect the item selected, and change styles to selected and the view from before
public void setItemViewMode(View item, boolean selected) {
    Animation animationImage;
    ImageView img = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    if(selected) {
        animationImage = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f);
    }
    else {
        animationImage = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);
    }
    animationImage.setDuration(250);
    animationImage.setFillAfter(true);

    img.startAnimation(animationImage);
}
```

As said above, the animation occurs, but, the alpha from the selected image is not 100% opaque.

May something wrong setting the opacity inside the animation?

Comment: You want 0.0f to 1.0f or 0.5f to 1.0f?

Comment: the image starts with 0.5f and when selected changes from that value to 1.0f to see it full opaque, so I understand that starts from 0.5f in the animation

Comment: Right, Did you try setting interpolator?

Comment: Nope, I'm new to android dev, so I'm going bit by bit to what they tell me to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it out, someway, I thought that before adding the animation, I should put the opacity to 1.0f and then make the animation from 0.5f to 1.0f, and this worked.

So it would be:

```
if(selected)
    animationImage = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f);
else
    animationImage = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);

img.setAlpha(1.0f);
img.startAnimation(animationImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this...**

```
public void setItemViewMode(View item, boolean selected) {
Animation animationImage;
ImageView img = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
if(selected) {
    animationImage = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1.0f);
}
else {
    animationImage = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0f);
}
animationImage.setDuration(250);
animationImage.setFillAfter(true);

img.startAnimation(animationImage);
```

}

Comment: just tried out, and happends the same to selected item, and then the passed item goes fully invisible (0.0f alpha)